# open_identifier values - what is the value for Facebook? & list somewhere?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

http://andrewblogs.com/blog/openid-for-asp-net-mvc-a-quick-setup/ - shows me values for "open_identifier" for Google, Yahoo, and MyOpenID.  Do you know what they are for the other providers, such as Facebook?  Is there a master list out there somewhere?

Also, the article mentioned widgets to make the buttons for each provider look fancy, similar to the login page on stackoverflow.com.  Do you know where these widgets can be found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fancy login look comes from the [OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) javascript client code.

Facebook doesn't support OpenID, so they don't have an identifier at all -- they use OAuth 2.0, which requires specialized handling.  There is no exhaustive list of all Providers, since anyone can be a Provider.
One notable Provider you didn't list but may be interested in is https://me.yahoo.com